# Как избежать сообщения: "Выражение int a[n] должно иметь константное значение"?

Tags: c, массивы

[image: Работающая программа][image: Возникшая в VS проблема]

Как сделать программу на Си с массивами типа int a[n] компилируемой в любой среде?

Comment: шото типа того `int n, *a; 
    scanf("%d", &n); 
    a = malloc(n * sizeof(a[0]));  ....... free(a);`

Comment: Просьба в дальнейшем не вставлять скрины кода и ошибок в вопрос, а копировать непосредственно текст.

Comment: Мы по программе еще не изучили указатели, есть другие варианты?

Comment: int a[] = { 0 }; - и все работает и без c99

Comment: Дополнил ответ. То, что Вы написали объявляет массив размером 1. Какой у Вас компилятор?

Comment: @Konstantin работает в mingw и VS, смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поддержка массивов переменной длины введена в `C99`. Поэтому, данная программа должна успешно собираться компиляторами, поддерживающими этот стандарт.
Однако использования таких конструкций лучше избегать потому что этот массив обычно размещается в стеке, размер которого ограничен, причём нет возможности проверить наличие места - если места не хватит, то программа в лучшем случае аварийно завершится, а может и просто вести себя непредсказуемо.
Лучше использовать динамическую память (`malloc` и `free`).

**UPD**

Либо, если по каким-то причинам невозможно использовать динамическую память, статически (чтобы располагать не в стеке) объявлять массив константного размера и работать с ним. Только в этом случае необходимо быть внимательным на предмет выхода за границы массива.

Answer (score 0):

Написал код, который решает поставленную задачу без использования указателей и работает на всех имеющихся у меня компиляторах.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int n, i, t;
int a[] = { 0 };

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
printf("Введите количество элементов массива от 1 до 100: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("\n");
if (n >= 1 && n <= 100)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Нажмите 0 для ввода элементов массива с клавиатуры\nНажмите любую цифру для автоматического заполнения массива\n");
    printf("\nВвод: ");
    scanf("%d", &t);
    printf("\nОдномерный массив: ");
    if (!t)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
    int zero1st = -1, zero2nd = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (a[i] == 0)
        {
            if (zero1st == -1)
                zero1st = i;
            else if (zero2nd == -1)
                zero2nd = i;
            else
                break;
        }
    double prodBetwZeros = 1;
    if (zero1st != zero2nd)
    {
        for (i = zero1st + 1; i < zero2nd; i++)
            prodBetwZeros *= a[i];
    }
    if ((zero2nd == -1) || ((zero2nd - zero1st) <= 2))
    {
        printf("\nНет чисел между первыми нулями\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nПроизведение чисел между первыми нулями: %.0lf\n", prodBetwZeros);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Этот код протестирован? Он работает при `n=100`?

Comment: @Konstantin Да, сейчас прикреплю скриншот

Comment: а если поменять местами `int n,i,t;` и `int a[]={0};` при `n=100` будет работать?

Comment: @Konstantin Спасибо за помощь, для этой задачи можно просто написать int a[100] = { 0 }. Видимо не зря ставят ограничения в задаче, про универсальное решение подобных задач нам еще не рассказали.